# Matching url params in Ionic with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-router, url-parameters

I am developing a `FunctionalComponent`that will render a list of items, in `Ionic` with `React`. The component will be reused for every type of item's status. I am passing the item's status as a `url-param`.

I want to get the `url-param`and display it as the List Title and use it to call the API for the matched items. Rendering the `List-Component`the url param's `match`renders as undefined.

How can I get the url param in the **Component**?

Link to the `List-Page` at **Dashboard.tsx:**

```
<IonCard className="card-body" href="/list/onschedule">
```

**App.tsx:**

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact={true} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/list/:status" component={List} />
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

In the `PrivateRoute`component I placed a `console.log` for the props and it's getting the param:
    [image]

**List.tsx:**

```
interface StatusMatchProps extends RouteComponentProps<{
  status: string;
}> {}

const List: React.FunctionComponent<StatusMatchProps> = ({match}) => {
  console.log("match: " + match)

  return (
    <>
      <IonTitle>{match.params.status}</IonTitle>
  );
};
```

**Chrome's console output:**

[image]

Comment: __Rendering the List-Componentthe url param's matchrenders as undefined.__ How is the list component rendered? It is rendered as standalone component or rendered when the path matches with the path of the PrivateRoute that is declared?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the `PrivateRoute`Component not passing the props. This is the working version of the Component:

```
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  component: any
}

export const PrivateRoute: FunctionComponent<PrivateRouteProps> = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (

<Route {...rest} render={props => {
    const currentUser: string | null  =  localStorage.getItem("userID");

    if (!userID) {
        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    }

    // authorised so return component
    return <Component {...props} />
  }} />
);
```